# Display the date before the post title in recent posts widget

Tags: widgets, recent-posts

In the recent posts widget I have the post link first, and the post date second item, How can I change, to display the date in front of the post title?

Thank you.

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Események', 'ashe' ),
        'id'            => 'esemenyek',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'ashe' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="ashe-widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="widget-title"><h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2></div>',
    ) );
```

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'esemenyek' ) ) {
        echo '<div class = "esemenyek">';
            dynamic_sidebar( 'esemenyek' );
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

```
<li>
    <a href="..post link">Post Title</a>
    <span class="post-date">2020.07.26.</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this can't be done with filters, as it's hard-coded in the widget itself. You can see this [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php?rev=48410#L120) (currently latest version, referring to revision for accuracy over time).

What you can do is you can create your own widget, with the markup you wish. You can refer to [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/#developing-widgets) page on how to create your own custom widget.

There is a way to do this with JavaScript, but I would advice against it, as it's not a good practice to change the page markup client side, if that can be done server side.

Comment: thank you, as a workaround, I used CSS flexbox: 

````
.widget_recent_entries li {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
````

Comment: Neat! Don't you just love it when there are a lot of solutions for a problem?